# unable to set offset value on smoothscroll jquery

Tags: jquery, offset

I am using this code for smoothscroll to target links, but I can't set offset value `top` to `100px`:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
     target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
         scrollTop: target.offset().top
       }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: oh guys I've just figured it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured it out myself .So I want to share it.

```
    $(function() {
   $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      var target_pos = (target.length > 0) ? target.offset().top : 0;
        var rhd = $('.navtop');
        var rhd_height = (rhd.length > 0) ? rhd.outerHeight() : 190;//change this value to get your desired offset value
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              target_pos -= rhd_height;

        if (target_pos > 0) {

           $('html,body').animate({

              scrollTop: target_pos

           }, 1000);

           return false;

        }
    }
  });
});
```

I tried to set to offset value top to my fixed nav bar.It work's fine for me.